# API versioning in Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, symfony4, api-versioning

I've been trying to find a solution to versioning in Symfony.
What would be the best way to do API versioning in Symfony. In Laravel this is pretty simple, [see here](https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt)

You just separate everything in different folders like V1/V2... and you create routes that points to that folder (namespace). But Symfony works differently, it uses annotation to create routes

Answer (score 8):

Symfony also provide easy way to version your code. 
So if you want to separate your controllers in different folders like `v1`,`v2` etc. then you can when import routes add prefix for each folder.

So in  `config/routes/annotations.yaml` or `app/config/routing.yml` file  you can define:

```
v1_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/v1  # add correct path
    type: annotation
    prefix: '/v1'

v2_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/v2  # add correct path
    type: annotation
    prefix: '/v2'
```

So after this all routes in `v1` folder will have prefix `v1`.

Please check [symfony routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html).